# Using result from android's AccountManager.getAuthToken via Zend_Gdata (401 unauthorized)

Tags: php, android, zend-gdata, accountmanager

I need to retrieve an auth token from an Android device (client side) using [AccountManager.getAuthToken](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#getAuthToken%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20android.app.Activity,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Candroid.os.Bundle%3E,%20android.os.Handler%29) and then re-use it via Zend_Gdata (server side)

When using the calendar 'cl' *authTokenType* things work as expected,

Android source:

```
String calendarToken = getAuthToken(account, 'cl' ...
```

PHP source:

```
$token = // value retrieved via Android 'calendarToken'

$client = new Zend_Gdata_HttpClient;
$client->setClientLoginToken($token);

$gData = new Zend_Gdata($client);
$feed = $gData->getFeed("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full");
```

This does work, however when using the Gmail '**mail**' *authTokenType* things are not so smooth

Android source:

```
String mailToken = getAuthToken(account, 'mail' ...
```

PHP source:

```
$token = // value retrieved via Android 'mailToken'

$client = new Zend_Gdata_HttpClient;
$client->setClientLoginToken($token);

$gData = new Zend_Gdata($client);
$feed = $gData->getFeed("https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/");
```

This keeps throwing a 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Expected response code 200, got 401.

I tried to follow guidelines for the various [Google Data APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/gdata/faq.html#GmailAtomFeed) with no luck

Answer (score 0):

The only reason you should see a difference between AuthSub requests to two services is a scope issue. Review item number three in [the AuthSub docs](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/AuthSub.html#WorkingAuthSub) and check to make sure the token you're using has access to GMail.